# When is my summer lilac ready for the next phase of my guerrilla gardening plan?

Tags: cuttings

The "landscaping" in front of my apartment building is less than attractive. Nobody ever does anything so I came up with the idea to plant something nice on my own. Not wanting to spend money on this experiment I searched the neighborhood and tool a cutting from a summer lilac shrub in the area.

My first cutting didn't make it but this one has finally sprouted some roots in the water glass I'm keeping it.

I assume that at some point I'll probably have to transplant it to a pot with soil before moving it to the front of the house. But I am unsure when to do that. How big should the roots be for potting? The cutting itself is about 20cm.

Answer (score 1):

According to Thomas DeBaggio in *Water Works: Rooting Cuttings in Water*, when [1/4 to 1/2 inch long](http://www.motherearthliving.com/gardening/water-works?pageid=3#PageContent3).